# Independence of $p$ of Hodge-Tate weights

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth and proper variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then for each prime $p$ we have the representation $R_p=H^i_{et}(X\times \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}, \mathbb{Q}_p)$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Is there an elementary way (in particular avoiding the comparison theorems) to show that the Hodge-Tate representations among $R_p$'s all have the same Hodge-Tate weights (one does not necessarily have to show that all $R_p$'s are Hodge-Tate though they are by Faltings's comparison theorem)?

Comment: By "elementary" I guess you mean without using the Hodge-Tate or de Rham comparison theorems? Then the answer is no.

Comment: Why is this conclusion true?

Comment: Because the only known way to prove that these representations are Hodge-Tate is to use the Hodge-Tate comparison theorem...